# Show that $\mathcal{V} = \text{ker}(f) \oplus \text{span}(v)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a finite-dimensional K-vector space, $f : \mathcal{V} \rightarrow K$ a linear one
mapping and $v \in \mathcal{V} \setminus \text{ker}(f)$. How could I show that $\mathcal{V}$ = ker($f$) $\oplus$ span($v$)? I've seen some posts about the variations of what ker($f$) $\oplus$ im($V$) would equal to, but I'm having trouble finding anything about span on here. If you have an idea of how to approach this question, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a linear functional. Let $N_f$ and $R_f$ be null and range space of $f$, respectively. Since $R_f$ is subspace of $K$, we have $0\leq \dim (R_f)\leq \dim (K)$. It’s easy to check, $\{1_K\}$ is basis of $K$. So $\dim (K)=1$ and $0\leq \dim (R_f)\leq 1$. Since $\exists v\in \mathcal{V}\setminus N_f$ (i.e. $v\neq 0$), we have $\dim(R_f)\neq 0$. So $\dim (R_f)=1$. By rank-nullity theorem, $\dim (N_f)=n-1$. Rest of the proof is special case of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4615966/861687) problem.